# Consistent use of personal pronouns

Tags: pronouns

Here is a excerpt from a dialog between a restaurant client and a waiter from an Italian source:

> -- La minestra è fredda. 
> -- La prego di accettare le mie scuse. Gliene porto un’altra.

My question is: Are "La" in "La prego" and "Gliene" used correctly together in this discourse?
To my understanding, "La prego..." implies the waiter is apologizing to a female client, and "Gliene porto..." implies that the waiter will bring the dish to a male client, which is contradictory. I think the dialogue will be correct if the waiter says: **Lo** prego di accettare le mie scuse. **Gliene** porto un’altra. Or perhaps my understanding of this matter is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 2):

In Italian you can address someone informally (dare del tu) or formally (dare del lei).

> **Informal**: **Ti** prego di accettare le mie scuse.
> **Formal**: **La** prego di accettare le mie scuse.

"Ti" and "la" here are personal pronouns, and the sentences remain the same no matter the gender of the client.

For the same reason:

> **Informal**: **Te** ne porto un’altra.
> **Formal**: **Glie**ne porto un’altra.

Again, the sentences remain the same no matter the gender of the client.

The following is not a complete explanation of formal Italian, but I wish it can help in this case:

**Use of pronouns**

The pronouns (direct and indirect, weak and strong) used in formal Italian are those of the third singular feminine person (lei, sé, la, le), even if the addressed person is a male. In this case, "la" and "gliene" ("le"+"ne") are used.

**Verbs coniugation**

If the person addressed is the subject, the coniugation of verbs is also the third singular person. In this case, the subject is always the speaker (the waiter).

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that «gliene» isn't necessarily «gli» + «ne», but in your last example it's «le» + «ne». (I think that's what confuses the OP in the dialog.)